# Overheating ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 19.04, asus, 20.04, overheating, sql

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS laptop, and I noticed an overheating of my laptop. on the other hand in the version ubuntu 19.04 I did not notice this problem, is there a solution
thank you

Comment: Are you asking us how to control your fans? Or asking us something else?

Comment: I have a similar [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232813/ubuntu-20-04-shutdown-after-overheating). Apparently, installing the most recent kernel 5.6.7 from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) helped. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if your laptop wasn't overheating before and is overheating now, it could be the recent update or it could just be a coincidence.

Fans and cooling systems break down over time. Vents get clogged. Your machine is older today than it was yesterday -- that's how age works.

Possible solutions for overheating:

- Look into a kernel update
- confirm your fan and cooling system are working